# Material Design Icons

Tags: graphics, icons, design

Hi I am looking for a software very similar to [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none).

Is there any program for Ubuntu that does the same as this generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a web-browser tool, so it will work with any OS as long as they support Chrome. And fortunately, Ubuntu does so.

To install chrome through ppa (from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)):

1. To add key:

   ```
   wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. To add repository:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
   ```
3. Update repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. To install chrome:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I know that it's a web tool. Already used it but it has limited features. So I'm looking for a program that I can install in my machine. If there exist something like this for a linux (Ubuntu) machine. Help?

Comment: @GeneSmit - Let me check.

Comment: Thank you. I'm totally new to Ubuntu so don't know what to search for. Thanks again Rapheal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  That looks like a simple app to take a picture with the smart phone, or grab some pre-made clip art to make launcher icons, for that particular phone.  The Ubuntu phone OS, and Ubuntu touch are rather new, and it may take some time for developers to come up with apps for them. But if you have Ubuntu on your PC, you already have all the tools you need and more, and since it is Ubuntu, then I am sure it can interface with your Ubuntu phone easily to transfer the icons.

Comment: thank you for the info. I have Ubuntu on pc but don't own a Ubuntu mobile device. Can't afford to purchase one. Thanks again.